# Why is Hawaii time used for conference deadlines?

Tags: conference, deadlines

I saw a European conference post deadlines for paper submission in Hawaii time. Now I see requests coming from locations in Eastern Standard Time areas with Hawaii time deadline. Why is this?

Answer (score 24):

It's likely the most westward time zone with universities - or at least with a noticeably amount of academic work. Hawaii is in GMT-10, and in [GMT-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9211:00) there are only a few small island countries, probably without any university.

In short, if you put the deadline in Hawaii time, in nearly any place of the world you can just forget the clock and just mind the date. It is also a great way to avoid complains like "I meet the deadline but I missed the time because I didn't notice the time zone", because in any other zone the deadline would be earlier.

Comment: So the functional equivalent of [AoE time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth).

Comment: Incidentally, it appears American Samoa has a community college, but no 4-year college or university.  That seems to be the extent of academia in UTC-11, as far as I could find.